# How to import Material UI - InputLabel in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, codeigniter, material-ui

I'm Integrating this: [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/arcs/pen/OmZaex) over my project in `Codeigniter` 
I require to make simple Form using this. But after implementing `material-ui` in `CodeIgniter` i'm facing problem of :
Invalid token & Unexpected Token `}`   
As i'm new in `react` or `npm` i'm not getting this problem that what mistake i'm doing in my code.

I have installed:  `npm` 
Included other `cdn` of `.css` & `.js`

[image: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {]

I have installed `material-ui` in same folder  `javascript` of Project 
In `script.js` 
`import  {InputLabel} from './node_modules/@material-ui/core/InputLabel';`

In `main.php` 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js"></script>` 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@4.3.3/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>`

Please help to make this run smoothly. Please share your valuable feedbacks. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: import  {InputLabel} from '@material-ui/core';

Comment: @Domino987 still same error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

Comment: did you install it with npm i @material-ui/core ?

Comment: @nitin_kumar I think, you are installed [material-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/core) for react components. Right?

Comment: @GokulaKannanT Yes.. Exactly.. Is it wrong way.?

Comment: @Domino987 Yes..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ES6 imports, you need to use a transpiler such as [babel.](https://babeljs.io/)

Here is a working example of how this is done [example](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/cdn/index.html). Note that this is not the best way to do it for a production app as there will be performance issues.

As you stated you are a beginner, I highly recommend you check out the officially supported [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) project. This will hook you up with a powerful boiler plate for creating a production React app. With create-react-app, the ES6 imports you described in the question will work as expected.